# Edit txt files with batch adding strings beetween rows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to edit any rows in a txt like this

BEFORE

```
E:\nameab.mkv
E:\namecd.mkv
E:\nameef.mkv
```

AFTER

```
1*file*E:\nameab.mkv
2*file*E:\namecd.mkv
3*file*E:\nameef.mkv
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48639748/edit) your question and post what did you tried as code so far and try to explain more your request why did you want to make it as this form, i mean in which purpose ?

Comment: And isn't notepad enough?

Comment: i'm creating a simple batch file to generate a playlist basing to some folders...the content of this folders always change and i need something to generate a fresh version of playlist every time i want....i already do all the job but i need to create a system for add some text in every rows of a file...like the example....ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```bat
@echo off
set /a "count=0"
Set "InputFile=test.txt"
Set "OutPutFile=%~n0.txt"
Set "String2Add=*file*"
If exist "%OutPutFile%" Del "%OutPutFile%"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%InputFile%"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    echo !count!%String2Add%%%a
)>>"%OutPutFile%"
Start "" "%OutPutFile%"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to take a step into PowerShell, you might:

```
$count = 1
Get-Content '.\pl.txt' | ForEach-Object { "$count*file*$_"; $count++ }
```